# Are there any difference between these two?

Tags: python, tuples

I am a little lost, from my understanding there should be no difference between these two code lines. As I am creating a tuple list in both cases. But I feel like I am wrong, could you point where I am wrong and why.

```
class Meta:
    ordering = tuple(('-pub_date',))
```

And

```
class Meta:
    ordering = ('-pub_date')
```

Comment: Nope, they are different data structures. The first one is tuple with string in it, the second one being a string.

Comment: `tuple(('-pub_date',))` is redundant just use `('-pub_date',)`

Comment: Try printing the two. They are not the same object.

Comment: I think this is a common misconception that putting something in between brackets `()` makes it a tuple. No, brackets are actually not needed for creating a tuple e.g. `a = 1,2,3` is tuple, `a = 2,` is tuple. The comma`,` makes a tuple. Brackets are for improving readability. So, `a = (1)` -> `a = 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`type(('-pub_date'))` returns 'str', where `type('-pub_date',)` returns 'tuple'. The `(foo,)` expression is a call to create a tuple with only one element